# Rotate, Translate and and Zoom dynamically created image view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, matrix

Its may be repeated question but i didn't get any perfect clue or answer to my question.

I am trying to drag and drop images from one view to another, and trying to apply operation like translate,zoom and rotate image view on finger touch.
I went through most of the links for the same but all I getting is image get translate, zoom and rotate within image Matrix i.e. Image get rotate within its image view.

Problem is want to re size my image view too with image. I solved this problem for translate and zoom but I am getting stuck while doing for rotation.

Following is my code.

```
 switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only
                                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                    start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());

                                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
                                    mode = DRAG;
                                    break;

                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                                    oldDist = spacing(event);
                                    if (oldDist > 10f) {
                                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                                        midPoint(mid, event);
                                        mode = ZOOM;
                                    }
                                    lastEvent = new float[4];
                                    lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                                    lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                                    lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                                    lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                                    d = rotation(event);
                                    break;

                                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //first finger lifted
                                    delete.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
                                    mode = NONE;

                                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:                                   //second finger lifted
                                    mode = NONE;
                                    Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
                                    break;


                          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                          if (mode == DRAG) {
                                        delete.setImageResource(R.drawable.share);
                                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()- start.y);
                                        float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
                                        matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
                                        float TransX = matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                                        float TransY = matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                                        draggedImg.setX(draggedImg.getX()+TransX);
                                        draggedImg.setY(draggedImg.getY()+TransY);
                                         draggedImg.setPivotX(draggedImg.getX()+TransX+draggedImg.getWidth()/2);
                                         draggedImg.setPivotY(draggedImg.getY()+TransY-draggedImg.getHeight()/2);


                   } else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "In Zoom Mode");
                                        float newDist = spacing(event);
                                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                                        if (newDist > 10f) {
                                                Drawable drawing = draggedImg.getDrawable();
                                                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawing).getBitmap();
                                                scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);

                                                float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
                                                matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
                                                scaleX = matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                                                scaleY = matrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

                                                params.width = (int)(bitmap.getWidth()*scaleX);
                                                params.height =(int)(bitmap.getHeight()*scaleY);

                                                float TransX = matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                                                float TransY = matrixValues[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                                                draggedImg.setPivotX(mid.x);
                                                draggedImg.setPivotY(mid.y);

                         draggedImg.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                                                draggedImg.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                                                draggedImg.setLayoutParams(params);
                                        }
                                        if (lastEvent != null) {
                                            Drawable drawing = draggedImg.getDrawable();
                                            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawing).getBitmap();
                                                float newRot = rotation(event);
                                                float r = newRot - d;                                               

                      draggedImg.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
                                                matrix.postRotate(r, v.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,v.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
                                               float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
                                               matrix.getValues(matrixValues);

  }

                                    }
                       }

                            return true; // indicate event was handled

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: And where exactly are you "stuck"?

Comment: When I trying to rotate image it rotated within image view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try [MultiTouchLibrary](https://github.com/thuytrinh/android-collage-views) . It will fulfill your need 
This library provide you below functionality

1. Rotate
2. Scale Image (Pinch to zoom)

Comment: How could i add that xml child elements dynamically by code. Because I created Image View dynamically.

Comment: you need to set imageView.setOnTouchListener(new MultiTouchListener(this));

Comment: You can also apply setOnTouchListener(new MultiTouchListener(this)) to your xml imageView child also . Please send me your xml file if you dont understand my point

Comment: hey how to get exact X,Y values of image. I tried but values I get is negative also. i just want to know when image get overlap to another layout.

Comment: I didnt get your reply ,Can you please explain  what you want exactly ?

Comment: As your demo shows we can drag the images on layout. I have one more layout at the end of screen. When image get overlap with this lower layout It get removed automatically. For this I want to get position of both image that we rotate,translate and lower layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90225/discussion-between-rupesh-nerkar-and-android-weblineindia).